# sunburnt : SolrError while parsing response

Tags: python, solr, sunburnt

I came upon the following error trace while just playing with this interface I plan to use in a Django app:

> > > import sunburnt
> > >       si = sunburnt.SolrInterface`("http://localhost:8984/solr/sprod/")`
> > >       si.query(global_attr_article_type='casual shoes').execute()
> > >           Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >             File "", line 1, in 
> > >             File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sunburnt/search.py", line 599, in execute
> > >               result = self.interface.search(**self.options())
> > >             File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sunburnt/sunburnt.py", line 212, in search
> > >               return self.schema.parse_response(self.conn.select(params))
> > >             File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sunburnt/schema.py", line 510, in parse_response
> > >               return SolrResponse(self, msg)
> > >             File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sunburnt/schema.py", line 652, in **init**
> > >               self.result = SolrResult(schema, result_node)
> > >             File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sunburnt/schema.py", line 691, in **init**
> > >               self.docs = [schema.parse_result_doc(n) for n in node.xpath("doc")]
> > >             File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sunburnt/schema.py", line 519, in parse_result_doc
> > >               return dict([self.parse_result_doc(n) for n in doc.getchildren()])
> > >             File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sunburnt/schema.py", line 516, in parse_result_doc
> > >               values = [self.parse_result_doc(n, name) for n in doc.getchildren()]
> > >             File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sunburnt/schema.py", line 525, in parse_result_doc
> > >               return name, SolrFieldInstance.from_solr(field_class, doc.text or '').to_user_data()
> > >             File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sunburnt/schema.py", line 326, in from_solr
> > >               self.value = self.field.from_solr(data)
> > >             File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sunburnt/schema.py", line 161, in from_solr
> > >               return self.normalize(value)
> > >             File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sunburnt/schema.py", line 219, in normalize
> > >               (value, self.**class**, self.name))
> > >           SolrError:  is invalid value for class 'sunburnt.schema.SolrFieldType_SolrIntField_indexed_True_omitNorms_True_stored_True' (field designer)  `

The designer field in the indexed document is indeed empty
`<arr name="designer">
    <int/>
    </arr>
    <arr name="discount">
    <float>0.0</float>
    </arr>
    <arr name="discount_label">
    <str/>
    </arr>`

and here's what the schema's got

`<fieldType name="integer" class="solr.IntField" omitNorms="true"/>

..

...

....

<field name="designer" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

I understand this has to do with the field being empty but since the schema doesn't mention 'required' = true anywhere for this field, I wonder what's really up.

Answer (score 0):

I guess

```
<arr name="designer"> <int/> </arr>
```

implies you are trying to store a multi-valued integer field in Solr? But your field definition for `designer` requires a single-valued integer. If you don't have a designer field for the document, then the document you index should have nothing for this field.